# Does the clojure-1.6.0.jar contain the source code and/or JavaDoc?

Tags: clojure

I have extracted clojure-1.6.0.jar and am having trouble locating the source and/or JavaDoc. Is it packaged with it? If not, where is my IDE picking up the JavaDocs from? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clojure-1.6.0.jar` is only the library, but it has the embedded javadoc for reference (you could check the build.xml for the clojure-1.6.0.zip, the compile sections includes ).

You could download the clojure source code from github: https://github.com/clojure/clojure

The documentation (including javadoc) is online at: http://clojure.org/documentation

Comment: thanks, so where is my IDE picking up the source/docs from if it is not on my system?

Comment: Are using Eclipse with the Counterclockwise plugin? What do you mean by docs picking up by your IDE?

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ and when you click over the class/method/function it has a pop-up with the JavaDoc. If all I downloaded is the clojure jar then where is it coming from? Over the net?

Comment: Now i get it, check the updated answer, the javadoc is embedded in the library, that's the reason why your IDE has the correct pop-up with documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the full Javadoc for all stable versions of Clojure here :
http://polekilroysoft.github.io/ClojureJavadoc/